# Define list with valuse in postgres with node.js

Tags: node.js, database, postgresql, schema, psql

I need to define such table with psql, and one of requirements is a field

```
● option:​255 chars, comma separated list: color, shade, form, weight
```

I am new to psql, worked only with mongodb before;

Cant understand how to define 255chars/comma separated list with such values provided

Comment: Do **not** store comma separated values in a single column. Read up on database normalization.

Comment: To extend on the first comment, you are misusing the most important principles of a relational database - normalization. You absolutely should read about that and understand it, if you are to design a sensible system.

Answer (score 0):

It means that you need to declare a column with varchar(255).  This column will be used to store a comma separated list.